# "to do about it" vs "to do with it"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> It’s too late **to do anything about it** now.
>
> It’s too late **to do anything with it** now.

As I know it, these two sentences are used. Is there any difference in their meaning or using? For me, the translation is pretty much similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Do something with* must refer to a physical object.

> My hair is so frizzy today, I can't do anything with it.

*Do something about* can refer to a situation.

> The closing date was yesterday? Well, it's too late to do anything about it now.

Comment: But, Kate, my dear, what are you doing about your hair? You simply cannot go to the party with it like that. :) [Just putting what you said into practice, as an example.]